# deleting specific json element - mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

i want to delete one specific point out of my db

```
// DB layout

{
    id: 9243
    email: asd@asd.asd
    //stuff
    point0:{
        //stuff
        point1:{
            //stuff
            point2:{
                //stuff (dynamic)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

now i want to delete point2 out of my db - without! knowing whats inside of it

```
//actual state of dev:

collection.update({'email': mail}, { $pull: elem }, function(err){

//tested:
elem = { "point0.point1" : "point2" }
elem = "point0.point1.point2"
elem = { "point0.point1.point2" : "" }
pullAll
... etc
```

Answer (score 2):

have you tried using `$unset` to remove the value `point2`?

```
collection.update({'email' : mail}, {$unset : {'point0.point1.point2' : 0}}, function (err) {})
```